# Insert query Optimization

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Hi i am new to Database Designing and i have a Problem with my table.

I have a table named **Fund** and it looks like this,

```
     Fund
#==============#
#Transaction_id# 
#==============#
#User_id       # 
#==============# 
#Amount        #
#==============#
```

Whereas there is an another table named User_details and it looks like this

```
  User_Details  
#===============#
#User_id        #  
#===============#
#User_Name      #
#===============#
```

A single Transaction_id will be associated with multiple User_id(User_Details table) but not with all User_id.

Is there anyway i am able to achieve this in a Single Insert query ?

For Ex:
Insert into Fund(Transaction_id,User_id,Amount) values(1,(1,2,4),20); like this ?

//Note :Here (1,2,4) refers to User_id.

For a single Transaction_id(Fund),i can't insert Multiple rows of User_id because Transaction_id is PK.

Comment: You can insert several rows with one insert: `INSERT INTO Fund (Transaction_id, User_id, Amount) VALUES (1,1,20), (1,2,20), (1,4,20);` but not in the fashion that you've described in your example. Is this the kind of optimization you're looking for?

Comment: You need a cross reference table between these 2 tables if you want to link one transaction to multiple userids http://www.developerdrive.com/2011/12/the-xref-table-for-mysql/ basically your database design does not support the ability fo more than one user to be related to one transaction

Comment: @Fluff ___i can't insert Multiple rows of User_id because Transaction_id is Primary Key___

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Oups, missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

You need a cross reference table to allow you to have more than one `User_Details` associated with one `Fund`

Fund

```
#================#
#Transaction_id  # 
#User_id         # 
#Amount          #
#================#
```

User_Details

```
#===============#
#User_id        #  
#User_Name      #
#===============#
```

Fund_Users_xref

```
#=================#
#Transaction_id   #
#User_id          #  
#=================#
```